# WAMPServer crashed on Windows 10 - how can I backup all MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, apache, windows-10, wampserver, httpd.conf

WAMPServer won't start up any services for some reason (worked fine until 2 weeks ago -- nothing I can think of that changed, though wouldn't be surprised if Windows 10 forced some update) so I'm planning to uninstall and then reinstall. Before I do, I want to backup my content so that I can restore it once I get the new version installed from scratch.

I have already zipped the wamp64\www folder and now I'm trying to do mysqldump, but MySQL won't even start.

My question has two parts:

1. How can I start MySQL service on Windows 10 home (no group policies or any such in-depth admin capabilities) when it will not start? I've tried opening services.msc and manually restarting -- it just doesn't do anything. There is no error.
2. Is there a way to save all my MySQL databases in one go without launching MySQL?

Comment: Did you look in the error logs for a reason?

Comment: Did you look in the Windows Evebt Viewer for a reason?

Comment: SImpler to fix than throw away and start again

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the suggestion. What logs are you referring to and where are they located? I will check the Windows Event Viewer ... Is there anything specific I should look for?

Comment: `C:\wamp\logs` contain logs from Apache, PHP, MySQL. then [Windows Event Viewer](https://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-10/how-to-use-event-viewer-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

On my system database they are stored in `C:\Program Files (x86)\WampServer\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.53\data`.

You can try to start mysql locally with an executable on `wamp\bin\mysql\mysql-version\bin`.

Maybe your `wampp` won't start because another application is using the same port?

You can view running port on Command Prompt with:

```
C:\> netstat -a -b
```

- -a This switch displays active TCP connections, TCP connections with the listening state, as well as UDP ports that are being listened to.
- -b This netstat switch is very similar to the -o switch listed below, but instead of displaying the PID, will display the process's actual file name. Using -b over -o might seem like it's saving you a step or two but using it can sometimes greatly extend the time it takes netstat to fully execute.

You can search a specific port with :

```
netstat -aon | find "[PORT]"
```

- -o A handy option for many troubleshooting tasks, the -o switch displays the process identifier (PID) associated with each displayed connection. See the example below for more about using netstat -o.
- -n Use the -n switch to prevent netstat from attempting to determine host names for foreign IP addresses. Depending on your current network connections, using this switch could considerably reduce the time it takes for netstat to fully execute.

[More Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat)

Comment: Thanks Maxime. I ran the command but it seems like the output it is never-ending. Can you edit your answer to add steps on how to use `netstat -a -b`? For instance, I tried running `netstat -a -b > find :80`, but the command output just sits there. Also, I tried `netstat -ao` and there in no indication that port 80 is being used by anything.

Comment: Thanks Maxime. Your explanation helped me understand a little better. I used this command `netstat -aon | find ":80"` and received a list of 9 IPs. How can I get the program name from this?

Comment: Try with -b annotation